# Como puedo ocultar un menú al hacer scroll un mínimo de 10px¿?

Tags: jquery, scroll

Estoy atascado en ocultar un menu al acer scroll, de momento tengo esto, pero lo que busco es que se oculte o aparezca solo si se hace un minimo de scroll de 100px por ejemplo.
Alguien me puede ayudar¿?! la verdad es que le estoy dando vueltas y no salgo del atasco

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var posicionInicial = 0;
 $(window).scroll(function () {
     var positionActual = $(this).scrollTop();
     if ( positionActual < posicionInicial){
         $('.menu_bar').fadeIn(150);
     } else {
          $('.menu_bar').fadeOut(150);
         }
      posicionInicial = positionActual;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Si es para un punto relativo y quieres que se muestre solo después de bajar n pixeles debajo de ese punto de referencia:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var referencePosition = 0; // donde se almacena a partir de que top se muestra el navbar
 var lastPosition = 0; // Auxiliar para saber si estas bajando o subiendo
 
 $(window).scroll(function () {
 console.log($(this).scrollTop(),referencePosition);
     let positionActual = $(this).scrollTop();
     if ( positionActual > referencePosition){ //si estas debajo del punto de referencia, ocultar
         $('.menu_bar').fadeOut(150);
     } else { // si subistes arriba del punto de referencia mostrar
          $('.menu_bar').fadeIn(150);
         }
      if (positionActual>lastPosition){ // si estas bajando, actualizar punto de referencia a 50 pixeles arriba del scroll actual
        referencePosition=positionActual-50;
        }
        lastPosition=positionActual; // actualizar auxiliar para saber si subes o bajas

 });
 });
```

```css
.container {
height:1000px;
}

.menu_bar {
position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<div class="menu_bar">contenido</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

podés usar myMenuElement.clientHeight si myMenuElement tiene un height en css y window.scrollY que se lea dentro de un callback adjunto a un listener al window, básicamente, algo como esto:
(tené en cuenta que el clientHeight lo uso para no poner una altura quemada que se adapte al css, pero le podés poner cualquier número que querás)

[Podés ver el ejemplo más actualizado en codepen](https://codepen.io/LuisArmando-TC/pen/pmwBbE?editors=0100)

```js
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');

function watchMenu() {
  nav.style.top = `-${
    nav.clientHeight < window.scrollY ?
      nav.clientHeight : 0
  }px`;
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', watchMenu);
```

```css
body, ul {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  background: #f00;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  place-items: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

div {
  height: 600px;
  background: #333;
}

#contact {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#home">
        Home
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contact">
        Contact
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="home"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Pero yo lo que necesito es que se esconda al hacer scroll hacia abajo 100px y que al haber scroll hacia arriba 100 px que aparezca pero que lo hagas independientemente de su está al principio de la página o en cualquier otro punto

Comment: Podes poner UNA respuesta y editarla según se necesite, el OP te indique cosas que no sirven, etc.